# Logarithm problem with variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need help in going about solving this problem. Any help would be appreciated, I'm a bit stumped.

$log\displaystyle \frac{z}{y^6}=$

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Hello! Do you know the values of $z$ and $y$? Or you can just use these properties: $\log(\frac ab)=\log(a)-\log(b)$ and $\log(a^n)=n\log(a)$.

Comment: @RossMillikan Sorry just added the equal sign my mistake for not giving the full problem

Comment: @manooooh No the values of y and z are unknown

Comment: @shyanne well... It is just an expression, what is your task here? Expand it?

Comment: @manooooh Yes it says to expand the problem would it just be log(z)-log(y^6)?

Comment: @shyanne yes, good! Maybe you can go more far by saying $\log(y^6)=6\log(y)$. P.S. Math stuff also works in comment's section!

Comment: @manooooh There may be some assumption like $y>0$ for that to be true, however.

Comment: @manooooh haha thank you for helping me!

Comment: No, $y\in\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$ because $y^6>0$, and $y^6=0$ i.e. $y=0$ cannot be possible.

Comment: @manooooh Sure, and $y<0$ is going to be really fine when writing $6\log y$, won't it?

Comment: If we are talking about expressions, we can plug $6\log(y)$, but if we are talking about functions, then $\log(y^6)\neq6\log(y)$. The OP did not give a context.

Answer (score 0):

$$\log\left( \frac{z}{y^6} \right) = \log z - 6\log y$$

Comment: The expression $\frac{z}{y^6} > 0$ whenever $z > 0$ and $y \neq 0$.